# why am i getting 310 after i use sys.stdout() to print it, instead of getting only 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm getting some random number at the end of my output result with sys.stdout(name) instead of getting only required result. What am i doing wrong?

CODE:

```
import sys

print('enter first number: ')
no1 = int(sys.stdin.readline())
print('enter second number: ')
no2 = int(sys.stdin.readline())
print('enter third number: ')
no3 = int(sys.stdin.readline())

if (no1 > no2) and (no1 > no3):
    largest = no1
elif (no2 > no1) and (no2 > no3):
    largest = no2
else:
    largest = no3
print('largest: ', largest)     #this gives right result
print(sys.stdout.write('largest: %s' %largest))     #this gives some random int with result at the end
```

like this is a code to find largest of 3 numbers so if we enter first=1, second=2, third= 3,,I'm getting 3 with print but 310 with stdout(). 3 is the right answer here.

Comment: You are, for some strange reason, printing out the return value of `sys.stdout.write()` - which is the number of characters that were written.  So you get `3` from the write, followed by `10` from the print.

Comment: Thanks @jasonharper , it actually helped me. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to print expected result, following line of code is sufficient:

```
sys.stdout.write('largest: %s' %largest)
```

while the following line of code also prints the number of characters written long with the desired result

```
print(sys.stdout.write('largest: %s' %largest))
```

thanks to @jasonharper !